# ASP.NET complex validation in business / service layer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, service-layer, business-logic-layer

I am asking this because after long time searching I haven't found a good answer on this yet...

Here is what I want:

Example: I have a domain model "JobPosting" which a user should be able to change state to published, if it is still a draft. Before publishing I must not only validate the model properties I must also validate many different requirements regarding the user account, it's registered company etc. All this validation logic is put into a service layer. So far so good...

This is how my service layer looks like:

```
public IValidationResult ValidatePublish(JobPosting jobPosting){
    ...
}

public void Publish(JobPosting jobPosting){
    jobPosting.State = JobPostingState.Published;
    ...
}
```

Any my controller:

```
public ActionResult Publish(PublishViewModel model){
    ...
    var validationResult = _jobService.ValidatePublish(jobPosting);
    if(validationResult.Success){
        _jobService.Publish(jobPosting);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And here now my questions:

I want to be able to call the ValidatePublish from the controller to show validation errors in the view. However I must never be able to publish a job when validation fails.
So to have my code more robust I added a second validation check in my Publish method in service layer:

```
public void Publish(JobPosting jobPosting){
    if(ValidatePublish(jobPosting).Success){
        jobPosting.State = JobPostingState.Published;
        ...
    }
}
```

but I have not such a good feeling with this approach because now I am calling the validation twice when validation is OK during each controller publish request.

What do you think. Is the second call to much? Is there a better approach?
I am asking because my whole application looks like that and if I would ever forget a validation call in controller I might end up with an not allowed domain model state in database. That's why I added the second validation check in each service method.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts on this!!!

Comment: "I am calling the validation twice "  where are you calling the validation second time?

Comment: First call in controller: 
    var validationResult = _jobService.ValidatePublish(jobPosting);

Second time in service method Publish:
    if(ValidatePublish(jobPosting).Success){

Comment: then why are you validating again in the method? You can just publish directly.

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution might be to have the `Publisher` class require the `JobPosting` and `IValidationResult` objects as arguments.

```
public void Publish(JobPosting jobPosting, IValidationResult validation)
{
    if (validation.IsValid)
    {
        jobPosting.State = JobPostingState.Published;
        // other work here...
    }
}
```

Your `Controller` can then call the `Validator`, receive an `IValidationResult` and pass that back to the presentation layer if needed. Otherwise pass on to `Publisher`

```
public ActionResult Publish(PublishViewModel model)
{
    var validationResult = _jobService.ValidatePublish(jobPosting);
    if(validationResult.Success) _jobService.Publish(jobPosting, validationResult);
    else return View("error", validationResult);
}
```

Edit:

A cleaner solution may be to have the `Publisher` class return a `PublishAttempt` result.

```
public class PublishAttempt : IValidationResult
{
    public enum AttemptOutcome {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult Publish(PublishViewModel model)
{
    var attempt = _jobService.Publish(jobPosting);
    if (attempt.Success) return View("success");
    else return View("error", attempt.ValidationResults);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes this would be also an approach... but what I don't like with it is that I could pass any validation result instance... could even just create a new empty one which is always valid.

Comment: Oh thanks :-) yes i like that... maybe I combine your idea with my last answer :-) just because I need the ability the call only the validation method... e.g. when I want to call the service validation via ajax to show errors in "realtime"

Answer (score -1):

The following just came into my mind... what do you think:

I change my service method to:

```
public IValidationResult Publish(JobPosting jobPosting, bool validateOnly = false){
    var validationResult = ValidatePublish(jobPosting);
    if(validateOnly) return validationResult;

    jobPosting.State = JobPostingState.Published;
    ...
    return validationResult;
}
```

And then in controller I always call only the Publish method and not the extra ValidatePublish anymore:

```
public ActionResult Publish(PublishViewModel model)
{
    var validationResult = _jobService.Publish(jobPosting);
    if(!validationResult.Success) return View("error", validationResult);
}
```

And when I need only simple validation I do

```
var validationResult = _jobService.Publish(jobPosting, true);
```

Is this okey to do it like that?
Or is it not good looking if a normal service call returns IValidationResult?

Comment: Or do you think its better to implement some kind of result per service method?